# Why are there two photons in pair production Feynman diagram?

Tags: photons, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, pair-production

Given

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323384550_ELECTROWEAK_INTERACTION_AND_ITS_TESTS_Bachelor_Thesis]

I wonder why are there two photons entering in a) pair production?
Isn't it one photon resulting in $e^+e^-$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to satisfy both energy and momentum conservation with only one photon.

Comment: This is easily seen: For the reverse process, pair annihilation, you can go to the rest frame where the momentum is zero. However, a real photon always moves at the speed of light, there is no rest frame.

Comment: Right, I remember! :) But another question that arises: When I need a photon that takes a recoil: How/why do the photons interact with each other?
Btw, why is a photon resulting in e-e+ in general? :D

Comment: @Ben *"why is a photon resulting in e-e+ in general?"* That probably deserves a fresh question (if it doesn't exist already).